# Disabled past months in monthpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a monthpicker something like datepicker and I want to disable past days or I have reserved day and and I want to give them to class.
My codes are below but I guess related code is this

```
$('#monthpicker').monthpicker().on('monthpicker-change-year', function(e, year) {
  $('#monthpicker').monthpicker('disableMonths', [1, 2, 3, 4]); // (re)enables all
  if (year === '2017') {
    $('#monthpicker').monthpicker('disableMonths', [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  }
  if (year === '2019') {
    $('#monthpicker').monthpicker('disableMonths', [9, 10, 11, 12]);
  }
});
```

and this is the all code

```js
(function($) {
  var methods = {
    init: function(options) {
      return this.each(function() {
        var
          $this = $(this),
          data = $this.data('monthpicker'),
          year = (options && options.year) ? options.year : (new Date()).getFullYear(),
          settings = $.extend({
            pattern: 'mm/yyyy',
            selectedMonth: null,
            selectedMonthName: '',
            selectedYear: year,
            startYear: year - 10,
            finalYear: year + 10,
            monthNames: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            id: "monthpicker_" + (Math.random() * Math.random()).toString().replace('.', ''),
            openOnFocus: true,
            disabledMonths: []
          }, options);

        settings.dateSeparator = settings.pattern.replace(/(mmm|mm|m|yyyy|yy|y)/ig, '');

        // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet for this element
        if (!data) {

          $(this).data('monthpicker', {
            'target': $this,
            'settings': settings
          });

          if (settings.openOnFocus === true) {
            $this.on('focus', function() {
              $this.monthpicker('show');
            });
          }

          $this.monthpicker('parseInputValue', settings);

          $this.monthpicker('mountWidget', settings);

          $this.on('monthpicker-click-month', function(e, month, year) {
            $this.monthpicker('setValue', settings);
            $this.monthpicker('hide');
          });

          // hide widget when user clicks elsewhere on page
          $this.addClass("mtz-monthpicker-widgetcontainer");
          $(document).unbind("mousedown.mtzmonthpicker").on("mousedown.mtzmonthpicker", function(e) {
            if (!e.target.className || e.target.className.toString().indexOf('mtz-monthpicker') < 0) {
              $(this).monthpicker('hideAll');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    },

    show: function() {
      $(this).monthpicker('hideAll');
      var widget = $('#' + this.data('monthpicker').settings.id);
      widget.css("top", this.offset().top + this.outerHeight());
      if ($(window).width() > (widget.width() + this.offset().left)) {
        widget.css("left", this.offset().left);
      } else {
        widget.css("left", this.offset().left - widget.width());
      }
      widget.show();
      widget.find('select').focus();
      this.trigger('monthpicker-show');
    },

    hide: function() {
      var widget = $('#' + this.data('monthpicker').settings.id);
      if (widget.is(':visible')) {
        widget.hide();
        this.trigger('monthpicker-hide');
      }
    },

    hideAll: function() {
      $(".mtz-monthpicker-widgetcontainer").each(function() {
        if (typeof($(this).data("monthpicker")) != "undefined") {
          $(this).monthpicker('hide');
        }
      });
    },

    setValue: function(settings) {
      var
        month = settings.selectedMonth,
        year = settings.selectedYear;

      if (settings.pattern.indexOf('mmm') >= 0) {
        month = settings.selectedMonthName;
      } else if (settings.pattern.indexOf('mm') >= 0 && settings.selectedMonth < 10) {
        month = '0' + settings.selectedMonth;
      }

      if (settings.pattern.indexOf('yyyy') < 0) {
        year = year.toString().substr(2, 2);
      }

      if (settings.pattern.indexOf('y') > settings.pattern.indexOf(settings.dateSeparator)) {
        this.val(month + settings.dateSeparator + year);
      } else {
        this.val(year + settings.dateSeparator + month);
      }

      this.change();
    },

    disableMonths: function(months) {
      var
        settings = this.data('monthpicker').settings,
        container = $('#' + settings.id);

      settings.disabledMonths = months;

      container.find('.mtz-monthpicker-month').each(function() {
        var m = parseInt($(this).data('month'));
        if ($.inArray(m, months) >= 0) {
          $(this).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
        }
      });
    },

    mountWidget: function(settings) {
      var
        monthpicker = this,
        container = $('<div id="' + settings.id + '" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" />'),
        header = $('<div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all mtz-monthpicker" />'),
        combo = $('<select class="mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-year" />'),
        table = $('<table class="mtz-monthpicker" />'),
        tbody = $('<tbody class="mtz-monthpicker" />'),
        tr = $('<tr class="mtz-monthpicker" />'),
        td = '',
        selectedYear = settings.selectedYear,
        option = null,
        attrSelectedYear = $(this).data('selected-year'),
        attrStartYear = $(this).data('start-year'),
        attrFinalYear = $(this).data('final-year');

      if (attrSelectedYear) {
        settings.selectedYear = attrSelectedYear;
      }

      if (attrStartYear) {
        settings.startYear = attrStartYear;
      }

      if (attrFinalYear) {
        settings.finalYear = attrFinalYear;
      }

      container.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 999999,
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        width: '250px',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        textAlign: 'center',
        display: 'none',
        top: monthpicker.offset().top + monthpicker.outerHeight(),
        left: monthpicker.offset().left
      });

      combo.on('change', function() {
        var months = $(this).parent().parent().find('td[data-month]');
        months.removeClass('ui-state-active');
        if ($(this).val() == settings.selectedYear) {
          months.filter('td[data-month=' + settings.selectedMonth + ']').addClass('ui-state-active');
        }
        monthpicker.trigger('monthpicker-change-year', $(this).val());
      });

      // mount years combo
      for (var i = settings.startYear; i <= settings.finalYear; i++) {
        var option = $('<option class="mtz-monthpicker" />').attr('value', i).append(i);
        if (settings.selectedYear == i) {
          option.attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
        combo.append(option);
      }
      header.append(combo).appendTo(container);

      // mount months table
      for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        td = $('<td class="ui-state-default mtz-monthpicker mtz-monthpicker-month" style="padding:5px;cursor:default;" />').attr('data-month', i);
        if (settings.selectedMonth == i) {
          td.addClass('ui-state-active');
        }
        td.append(settings.monthNames[i - 1]);
        tr.append(td).appendTo(tbody);
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
          tr = $('<tr class="mtz-monthpicker" />');
        }
      }

      tbody.find('.mtz-monthpicker-month').on('click', function() {
        var m = parseInt($(this).data('month'));
        if ($.inArray(m, settings.disabledMonths) < 0) {
          settings.selectedYear = $(this).closest('.ui-datepicker').find('.mtz-monthpicker-year').first().val();
          settings.selectedMonth = $(this).data('month');
          settings.selectedMonthName = $(this).text();
          monthpicker.trigger('monthpicker-click-month', $(this).data('month'));
          $(this).closest('table').find('.ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-active');
          $(this).addClass('ui-state-active');
        }
      });

      table.append(tbody).appendTo(container);

      container.appendTo('body');
    },

    destroy: function() {
      return this.each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('mtz-monthpicker-widgetcontainer').unbind('focus').removeData('monthpicker');
      });
    },

    getDate: function() {
      var settings = this.data('monthpicker').settings;
      if (settings.selectedMonth && settings.selectedYear) {
        return new Date(settings.selectedYear, settings.selectedMonth - 1);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    },

    parseInputValue: function(settings) {
      if (this.val()) {
        if (settings.dateSeparator) {
          var val = this.val().toString().split(settings.dateSeparator);
          if (settings.pattern.indexOf('m') === 0) {
            settings.selectedMonth = val[0];
            settings.selectedYear = val[1];
          } else {
            settings.selectedMonth = val[1];
            settings.selectedYear = val[0];
          }
        }
      }
    }

  };

  $.fn.monthpicker = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.mtz.monthpicker');
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
$('#monthpicker').monthpicker().on('monthpicker-change-year', function(e, year) {
  $('#monthpicker').monthpicker('disableMonths', [1, 2, 3, 4]); // (re)enables all
  if (year === '2017') {
    $('#monthpicker').monthpicker('disableMonths', [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  }
  if (year === '2019') {
    $('#monthpicker').monthpicker('disableMonths', [9, 10, 11, 12]);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="monthpicker" placeholder=" When? ">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you have a month picker and you want to disable days :))) good one

Comment: sorry I want to disable months so sorry :))